# How to convert between GRAILS' class column and hibernate's DTYPE column in GORM

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have the following problem. I got a database schema generated by JPA/Hibernate in Java. I have one table for an inheritance hierarchy. For this to work Hibernate uses a DTYPE column to distinguish between the concrete implementations of the classes in my hierarchy.

I now need to load that same hierarchy to GRAILS domain objects. However GRAILS uses a column with the name 'class' to save the names of the concrete implementation and I was not able to find any way to change this mapping. So my question is: is there a way to map GRAILS' 'class' column to Hibernate's DTYPE column?

Comment: What specifically about the mapping are you trying to change? The column name, the datatype, etc??

Comment: I think I need to change the column name as well as the value each class is mapped to. But I think the answers below provide help in doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You can customise the name used for the discriminator column [in the base class `mapping` closure](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/discriminator.html).

```
class TopOfTheHierarchy {
  …
  static mapping = {
    discriminator column: "DTYPE"
  }
}
```

To use something other than the class name as the discriminator *value* you use a similar mapping entry for each subclass

```
class ChildClass {
  …
  static mapping = {
    discriminator "child"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm. I thought I already tried that. Ok, will try again over the next days. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a DB schema you can try using [Grails Database Reverse Engineering Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer) to generate your Grails domain class from your schema.